# How to use termios and ioctl functions in kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, ioctl

I wrote a kernel module for a touch screen monitor and earlier I used `inputattach` (written in userspace) to open serial port, set baud rate, control flags, line discipline etc.

But now I want to implement the functionalities of `inputattach` directly in our driver as we don't want to trigger our driver from an userspace program i.e `inputattch`.

But we cant able to set `c_ispeed`, `c_ospeed`, `c_cflag`, `c_iflag`, line discipline, etc., in `kernel` space.

Is there any solution to set baud rate, line discipline etc., by only using our `kernel` module?